"Weakest" regularity property ensuring a function $f$ maps bounded sets into bounded sets
Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a function.
I would like to know the weakest regularity property I must place on $f$ to ensure that $f$ maps bounded sets into bounded sets.
Note that uniform continuity is insufficient: A uniformly continuous function maps totally bounded sets into totally bounded sets, but not necessarily bounded into bounded if the domain lacks the Heine-Borel property.
On the other hand, a Lipschitz map does indeed map bounded sets into bounded sets. But Lipschitz continuity is a rather strong condition to impose, and I'd like to know if there is a weaker type of continuity that still guarantees this.

There's also Hölder continuity, but it's in the same lot as Lipschitz continuity.
